# In which way is it possible to update an app?

Tags: android

In which way is it possible to update an app? Except download the hole app thru the market.

To be more specific. Let say I have a app with a main menu with 3 choices
    1 Data
    2 Tools
    3 Settings

**For 1-Data...**
...gives you a new view with a menu(submenu) which each row give a view that contains normal data as text, pictures (maybey video). 
If all data must be stored on the phone to be reach offline.

*1.1* How can I update this kind of data? Like change/add some text, photo etc from a server??
    *1.2* Is it even possible to add new menu rows with new data from a server? Only know about xml menu but these feels so permanent.

**For 2-Tools...**
...that have a new submenu like before. But here the menu use hardware futures and api:s. Like, uses gps to get a position and show it on a map or make a call or something...

*2.1* For this kind of stuff, is it possible just to update a specific changed class that the app could download from a server or something similar?

**For 3-settings...**
...If you could change the language here.

*3.1* Is it possible to update the app from a server with a new language automtic when the translation is ready? Just download the xml:s?

Would be good instead of that you have to noties the user, so the user manually have to download the hole app again (< v2.2).

Im new to this, dont have the hole picture yet.

Answer (score 0):

The common way of doing this (which is accepted by anyone using an Android Device) is simply publishing the new App-version on the Android Market.

Although, it should also be possible to do it like you said but since Apps are not allowed to download runnable code their self (for security proposals) it doesn't madder. Also if you want to improve new functions, you might need more permissions to your Android Manifest (it would be very bad if this file could be edited at runtime...).

If you have an App which works like a client for an Online-Service, it's sure okay to update those contents, but the things you asked for should really be done using the normal App Market.